# Extracting month from date in flaskform with different format

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I am trying to create a code made out of months and count number. The count number is easy, but I don't understand how to extract month from date form.

Model:

```
req_date        =db.Column(db.Date, nullable=False, default=date.today())   
req_code        =db.Column(db.String, nullable=False, unique=True)
```

Form:

```
reqdate     = DateField('Request Date')
```

Route:

```
 currentyear = extract('year',form.reqdate.data)
 currentmonth= extract('month', form.reqdate.data)
 ronum  = 'RO-'+'/'+str(currentmonth)+'/'+str(currentyear)
```

I tried using this function for my route I found before, but it doesn't seem to work.
What I got instead of like `RO-/01/2021`. I got this error:

> RO-/EXTRACT(month FROM :param_1)/EXTRACT(year FROM :param_1)

Does anyone know the function to extract it? Or if the function isn't wrong, where did I go wrong?

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include the definition of  `extract`?  Or if it's a database function, show the query and tell us which database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DateField` returns a `datetime.date` object

That means you should be able to do:

```
# Data from the form which has been formatted to datetime.date object
current_date = form.reqdate.data

current_year = current_date.year
current_month = current_date.month
```

Attributes available on `datetime.date` can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#available-types)